# Angular 5 : ng build -- prod freezes the app performances and stability

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-cli, gzip

I'm running under **Angular 5.2.9** and **angular-cli : 1.6.8**

My problem is that when i'm working within dev mode (`ng serve`) , everything is OK , but when running `ng build --prod` the generated **(2.5 mo)** app is messy , too slow , and crashes fastly within few clics.

I ve switched to build my app within :

```
ng build --target=development --env=dev --aot --build-optimizer --sourcemaps=false --named-chunks=true --output-hashing=all --extract-css=false
```

that resolved my problem of performances , but it's still too heavy **(8 mo)** and that make the app too heavy in the initial loading.

I was told that i's relative to the **gzip** of the genereted app.

Is there any way to do the **gzip** action within `ng build --target=developement` **?**

Comment: `ng build -prod` shouldn't cause your app to slow down/crash - if anything, it should speed up due to the templates being pre-compiled! I'd research the root cause of that issue rather than trying to avoid production mode entirely.

Comment: As @JoeClay stated, you should look at the root of the problem. In most cases the cause is an outdated or poor designed third party plugin or npm package. Make sure you have every package in the state of compatible with v5

Comment: @Fals : even if there is some 3rd libraries probleme , why would it work in dev mode ? , alos , the compression action won 't be controlable ?

Comment: @firasKoubaa because of all the optimization and some cases aot messes older 3rd lib, which can be outdated **ng build --prod: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build** and **aot: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler**

Comment: Check enviroment differences environment.prod.ts and environment.ts. Also you can build prod build with --prod, --aot=false optimizer = false and sourcemaps=true ,then debug and find out where the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

Update your angular-cli to latest 1.7.3 and recheck the prod build once.
I Hope it will work.

Comment: newest angular-cli versions have some issues on compiling the lazy loading done with (()=>) in routing files , it s for that i ve downgrated to angular cli 1.6.8

Answer (score 0):

on `angular/cli` v1.7.3 will halt console commands `--sourcemap=true`, also `--buildOptimizer` so on 1.6.8 it will work as should. FYI.